# Query string not passing correctly to Action Link

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this action link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export to Excel",  // link text
    "Export",                        // action
    "Members",                       // controller
    Request.QueryString,             // query string
    "excel");                        // class
```

Using my own overloaded Action Link method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText, string action, string controllerName,
    NameValueCollection queryString, string className)
{
    var newRoute = new RouteValueDictionary();

    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes =
        new Dictionary<string, object> {{"class", className}};

    newRoute = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.ToRouteDic(newRoute);

    return HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, 
        htmlHelper.RouteCollection, linkText, null, action, null,
        newRoute, htmlAttributes).ToMvcHtml();
}
```

So this is the url of the page on my on:

> mysite.com/Members?searchName=&searchEmail=&agencyId=&agencyTypeId=&regionId=&regionId=67&searchTaxIdNum=&searchDateStart=&searchDateEnd=

And the Action Link I have generates this url:

> mysite.com/Members/Export?regionId=%2C67

So for some reason `%2C` is getting added to the `regionId`, but I'm not sure. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

%2 in a URL is equivalent to a blank space, you probably have a blank space somewhere in your code.